# Query for multiple array elements in Postgres JSONB column

Tags: arrays, postgresql, jsonb

I have a table mydata jsonb column containing an array of integers.

```
create table mydata
(
    name varchar,
    data jsonb
);
```

Here's some test data:

```
insert into mydata (name, data)
VALUES
('hello1', '[1]'),
('hello12', '[1,2]'),
('hello2', '[2]'),
('hello23', '[2,3]')
;
```

I now would like to query the table for elements, that contain either 2 or 3 (or both) in "data".
Is there a better syntax for this besides:

```
select * from mydata where (data @> '2' or data @> '3');
```

because it could be that I have more than 2 options to query for of course. I would assume that I'm able to do a subquery like this (not working, just as hint what I'd like to achieve):

```
create table other ( id bigserial , text varchar);
insert into other (id, text) values (1, 'x'), (2, 'y'), (3, 'y'), (4, 'z');
```

What I now want to do is, get all data from mydata where data has a reference to other_table

```
select * from mydata where (data @> IN (select distinct id from other_table where text='y'));
```

Thanks a lot,
Fritz

Comment: In your question you state that you want elements that contain "either 2 **or** 3" - which can be read that it shouldn't return elements that contain both - but that isn't what you query is doing. If you do want to also include elements that contain both values this would be easy with a native array as it supports the overlaps operator `&&` - but JSONB doesn't support that.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name sorry for the misunderstanding: I want all entries that have 2 or 3 or both. will update description

Comment: If you only store integers in that column, I would recommend to use `int[]` instead of `jsonb` then this type of queries is way easier (`where data && array[2,3]`)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: yes, thanks! For this very specific usecase in question, this works perfect. Even with a subquery:
```
select * from mydata where data && array(select id from other where text = 'y');
```
(assuming data has now datatype bigint[]
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[step-by-step demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=b713bf73b475163fcf31afbe97454b6d)

```
SELECT DISTINCT                             -- 3
    name,
    data
FROM mydata,
   jsonb_array_elements_text(data) elems    -- 1
WHERE value::int IN (
    SELECT id FROM other WHERE "text" = 'y' -- 2
)
```

1. Extract all array elements into an own record
2. Filter former elements whether they are elements of the subquery
3. Because this filter could return same records twice (if the original data match both, `2` and `3`) the `DISTINCT` ensures to return unique records.

Comment: thanks. Still this is requiring to put all entries I want to query for in the list manually. I would like to have a subquery returning any number of results. Is this possible?

Comment: It's not clear to me what you want to achieve... Please add some sample data and the expected output to the **question**

Comment: updated the question with a second sample table. Should be clear now hopefully.

Answer (score 0):

If the IDs come from a different table, you could do something like this:

```
select *
from mydata m
where exists (select *
              from other o
              where o.id in (select v::int 
                             from jsonb_array_elements_text(m.data) as x(v)))
```

With Postgres 12 or later, you could use

```
select *
from mydata m
where exists (select *
              from other o
              where jsonb_path_exists(m.data, '$[*] ? (@ == $id)', jsonb_build_object('id', o.id)))
```

Not sure which one would be faster.