# Retrieve multiple fields from jsonb array in postgres

Tags: json, postgresql, jsonb

I'm wondering if I can retrieve multiple fields from postgres jsonb column. The jsonb dats format is something like:

```
{
    ...
    "teamId": 12,
    "teamName": "super team",
    "teamMembers": [
        {
            ...
            "memberId": 34,
            "externalId": 7783,
            "firstname": "John",
            "lastname": "Doe"
            ...
        }
    ]
    ...
}
```

What I'm trying to do is to fetch only `teamId`, `memberId`, `externalId` fields skipping all other fields.
This database is really huge so I'm trying to optimise this query to speed it up and reduce network load.

With a jsonpath plus I could fetch members fields with something like thus: `$.teamMembers.[teamId, externalId]` but it seems postgres doesn't support such a syntax.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Query for multiple array elements in Postgres JSONB column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66114686/query-for-multiple-array-elements-in-postgres-jsonb-column)

Comment: Do you want to fetch the team members as a relation (with 3 columns)? Or do you want to fetch them as a JSON (array of) object(s), per row in the input relation? Or something else?

Comment: Consider `jsonb_to_recordset` ([example A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77787934/1048572), [example B](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76791902/1048572))

Comment: @tomredfern Why [[tag:jsonpath-plus]]? Postgres doesn't support that, it seems unrelated to the question.

Comment: @Bergi good spot, my bad

Answer (score 2):

Flatten the JSONB column using `jsonb_array_elements` and a [lateral join](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-LATERAL). Then do a trivial select.
The `t` CTE is a mimic of the real table.

```sql
with t(id, jsonfield) as
(
 values
 (1, '{
    "teamId": 12,
    "teamName": "super team",
    "teamMembers": [
        {"memberId": 34, "externalId": 7783, "firstname": "John", "lastname": "Doe"},
        {"memberId": 134, "externalId": 17783, "firstname": "Kate", "lastname": "Doe"}
    ]
   }'::jsonb),
 (2, '{
    "teamId": 22,
    "teamName": "super team",
    "teamMembers": [
        {"memberId": 35, "externalId": 7784, "firstname": "Peter", "lastname": "Doe"},
        {"memberId": 135, "externalId": 17784, "firstname": "Ada", "lastname": "Doe"}
    ]
   }'::jsonb)
)
select (jsonfield ->>'teamId')::integer as teamid, 
       (jarr ->> 'memberId')::integer as memberid, 
       (jarr ->> 'externalId')::integer as externalId
from t, lateral jsonb_array_elements(jsonfield -> 'teamMembers') jarr;
```

| teamid | memberid | externalid |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12 | 34 | 7783 |
| 12 | 134 | 17783 |
| 22 | 35 | 7784 |
| 22 | 135 | 17784 |

This approach is a possible PostgreSQL's functional equivalent of `JSON_TABLE` in Oracle/MySQL and `OPENJSON` in MSSQL. Another one as @Bergi commented is to use `jsonb_to_recordset`.